# Fnd links containing particular string in href and remove href between slashes with javascript only

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a use case, where i have to select all `<a>`, containing string in url like "/web/local" and remove "/web/local" from all href of all these links.

Note: i can't use jQuery. I can use either pure js or YUI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your efforts till now ? please add code you have tried so far

Comment: I did some try with document.querySelector  + matches, but not sure how to use correctly. Also is there any method exists like .contain() ?

Comment: @designershyam You must provide snippets or samples of your code so people can offer suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('a') will return all anchor tags. Then you can inspect and compare the HREF properties of each of the returned elements and modify them as needed. I'll let you try the code first before posting an answer.

Comment: @daddygames `querySelectorAll('a')` will return a node list, not anchor tags.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Whoops! Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
let phrase = "/web/local";

// Get all the links that contain the desired phrase into an Array
let links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='" + phrase +"']"));

// Loop over results
links.forEach(function(link){
  // Remove the phrase from the href
  link.href = link.href.replace(phrase, "");
});

// Just for testing:
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("a"));
```

```html
<a href="http://www.something.com/web/local">Some Link</a>
<a href="http://www.something.com/web/local">Some Link</a>
<a href="http://www.something.com/web/local">Some Link</a>
<a href="http://www.something.com/web/local">Some Link</a>
<a href="http://www.something.com/web/local">Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get /set correctly the href attribute you need to use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)/[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/web/local"').forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.setAttribute('href', 
           ele.getAttribute('href').replace('/web/local', ''));

    console.log(ele.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<a href="/web/local"></a>
<a href="22222/web/local"></a>
<a href="/web/local"></a>
```

Comment: You don't "need" to use `set/getAttribute`. You can also work with the `.href` DOM property.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I know, but using the property href instead of attribute you change the href itself by adding full path...... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="http:///web/locale/google.com">Link 1</a>
    <a href="http:///web/locale/stackoverflow.com">Link 2</a>


    <script>

        var string = '/web/locale/';
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var link = links[i].getAttribute('href');
            link = link.replace(string, '');
            links[i].setAttribute('href', link);

        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a live node list and should only be used in rare use cases. Also, instead of getting all the links and working with the `href` on all of them, you really should just get the ones that need replacing in the first place.